# Creating arrays with size as a variable

Tags: java

I am trying to create a new array in this way:

```
final boolean[] arr = new boolean[list.size()];
```

This line is throwing a null pointer in my code in some cases. Under what situations can this happen? Can it happen when the list has zero elements? I am sure the list is not null at this stage.

Comment: It will throw NPE if list is null.

Comment: Check again, the only way that exact line will throw a nullpointer exception is that list is null.

Comment: Make sure you have initialized your list variable

Comment: I can't imagine another reason than list is null. How do you checked it? Can you show some code that you use to initialize list?

Comment: your list is null for sure as there are no statements which can throw NPE except for list.size() try to print size of your list to check whether its null or not

Comment: yes i was wrong. the list object is null, although a check was placed in some other part of the workflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can only happen, if `list` is `null`.
If `list` is empty, `list.size()` will return 0.

Comment: final boolean[] arr = new boolean[0]; will not throw any exception.

Answer (score 1):

Having a **NullPointerException** thrown, means you have an uninitialized object. It has nothing to do with anything else. If the exception is thrown out of the line you mentioned, then as the comments on your question says, your list hasn't been initialized.

To create an array using a dynamic length (Note that an array size CANNOT change after is has been initialized), you can do this:

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
//Add elements to your list
String[] arr = list.toArray(new String[list.size()]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
boolean[] arr = new boolean[0];
```

Even it is a valid syntax. you can create array with 0 size. So untill and unless `list` null it will not produce `NullPointerException`

Answer (score 0):

The null point can occur when `list` is null, if it's only occurring on that line. If that is the exception you're getting, then `list` is `null`. Have another look at your code, and I'm sure you'll find out. Alternatively, debug your code and check the value of `list` at this line.

Answer (score 0):

**list** was never instantiated. So, it is **null**. Check if you instantiated the list after declaration.

Answer (score 0):

Please use List instead of array and finally get the array from the list ..

Comment: Why? If the size if fixed I would go for array.

Comment: if the size is fixed, then its fine. but here the size is decided dynamically according to a list .. `list.size()' decides the size and hence it is not fixed, i assumed

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have **initialized your list variable**. The only way it will throw a NPE is due to the list itself being null.